# Determining all real functions $g=\frac{y}{x}$, where $y$ is an involution

Tags: functional-equations, involutions

Suppose that we have the following functional equation
$$y(x)=x \,g(x)$$
where both $y$ and $g$ are functions over the reals. In addition, we want $y(x)$ to be an
involution, i.e. $y(y(x))=x$, for some interval of the real line $\mathbb R$. Is there a straightforward way to determine all possible functions $g(x)$ for which $y(x)$ is an involution? (At least given some specific interval in the reals).

I am not sure whether this question is trivial or extremely simple, but I was not able to work out
an answer or find one in any reference.

Note added: We also want $y$ to be continuous and differentiable in the interval that is of interest.

Comment: Are there any continuity/differentiability assumptions?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I edited my post.

Comment: Finding all such y(x) and then dividing by x seems to be the most straightforward way.